# How to change color of table row when it is selected and row added through ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, css, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I added table rows dynamically through ajax in MVC C#. Now I want to change color of a row which is selected.
I applied same effect on table which rows are generated in html view.

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
   <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered TableforPatientVital" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>BP sys.</th>
            <th>BP dia.</th>
            <th>Heart rate</th>
            <th>Respiration</th>
            <th>Sugar</th>
            <th>Body temprature</th>
            <th>Oxygen saturation</th>
            <th>Weight</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="load-transactions">
         @foreach (var item in Model)
         {
         <tr id="jsonData">
            <td>
               <a href="javascript:showmychart(@item.PatientId)">  @item.FirstName &nbsp; @item.LastName</a>
            </td>
            <td>@item.BpSystolic</td>
            <td>@item.BpDiastolic</td>
            <td>@item.HeartRate</td>
            <td>@item.Respiration</td>
            <td>@item.Sugar</td>
            <td>@item.Temperature</td>
            <td>@item.OxygenSaturation</td>
            <td>@item.Weight</td>
         </tr>
         }
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <table id="Table2" class="table table-striped table-bordered TableforPatientVital" style="width:100%;">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>BP sys.</th>
            <th>BP dia.</th>
            <th>Heart rate</th>
            <th>Respiration</th>
            <th>Sugar</th>
            <th>Body temprature</th>
            <th>Oxygen saturation</th>
            <th>Weight</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="wrapbody"></tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

My Jquery code is

```js
function ShowDatainDataTable(value, category) {
    $('#Table2').css("display", "block");
    $('#example').css("display", "none");
    $('#BP-bar-chart-grouped').css("display", "none");
    if (value != null) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Dashboard/getDataByVitalsPriority",
            data: {
                value: value,
                category: category
            },
            success: function(response) {
                debugger;
                $('#wrapbody').empty();

                console.log(response);
                //var data = JSON.parse(response);
                if (response) {
                    //$('#example').html(response.data);
                    var len = response.data.length;
                    var name;
                    if (len > 0) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                            name = response.data[i].FirstName + " " + response.data[i].LastName;
                            var html = "<tr class='text-center'>";
                            html += "<td><a style='cursor:pointer;' onclick='showmychart(" + response.data[i].PatientId + ");'>" + name + "</a></td>";
                            html += "<td>" + response.data[i].BpSystolic + "</td>";
                            html += "<td>" + response.data[i].BpDiastolic + "</td>";
                            html += "<td>" + response.data[i].HeartRate + "</td>";
                            html += "<td>" + response.data[i].Respiration + "</td>";
                            html += "<td>" + response.data[i].Sugar + "</td>";
                            html += "<td>" + response.data[i].Temperature + "</td>";
                            html += "<td>" + response.data[i].OxygenSaturation + "</td>";
                            html += "<td>" + response.data[i].Weight + "</td>";
                            html += "</tr>"
                            $('#wrapbody').append(html);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function(result) {
                toastr.error('Service Time Out');
            }
        });
    } else {
        toastr.info("Patient value is not available, please select patient.");
        $("#divPageMessage").html("<div class='alert alert-dismissable alert-info appAlert'><strong><i class='fa fa-info'></i>&nbsp;Please select a patient. </strong></div>");
    }
}
```

I used code below to change row color when clicked, which is not working on this table

```js
$(".TableforPatientVital tbody tr").on('click', function(event) {
    $(".TableforPatientVital tbody tr").removeClass('row_selected');
    $(this).addClass('row_selected');
});
```

Please suggest me what to do?

Comment: Could you provide us with the html after the rows have been added to the tbody?

Comment: Yes sure, actually I put a div in which 2 tables.

Comment: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-bind-click-event-to-dynamically-added-elements-in-jquery.php you need to bind the onclick event to your dynamic created elements

Comment: Thank you. It is working but on all selected row, I want only one row selected at a time so previous row color should be normal.

Answer (score 0):

First off the ancestor you bind the event to should be 'static' IE not dynamically created. So if the table is created dynamically as well use a prior parent or `$(document)`.

then you can apply your function to your selected row by use of `$(this)`:

```
$(document).on('click','tr', function () {
  var clickedTR = $(this)  // the tr you clicked on
  alert(clickedTR.attr('id'));
  clickedTR.css('background', 'red'); // use it as you wish
});
```